# How can I generate RSS with arbitrary tags and enclosures

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

Right now, I'm using PyRSS2Gen to generate an RSS document (resyndicating a modification of an rss feed that was parsed with feedparser), but I can't figure out how to add uncommon tags to the item.

```
items = [
PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
    title = x.title,
    link = x.link,
    description = x.summary,
    guid = x.link,
    pubDate = datetime(
        x.modified_parsed[0],
        x.modified_parsed[1],
        x.modified_parsed[2],
        x.modified_parsed[3],
        x.modified_parsed[4],
        x.modified_parsed[5])
    )

for x in parsed_feed.entries]

rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
    title = "Resyndicator",
    link = parsed_feed['feed'].get("link"),
    description = "etc",

    language = parsed_feed['feed'].get("language"),    
    copyright = parsed_feed['feed'].get("copyright"),
    managingEditor = parsed_feed['feed'].get("managingEditor"),
    webMaster = parsed_feed['feed'].get("webMaster"),
    pubDate = parsed_feed['feed'].get("pubDate"),
    lastBuildDate = parsed_feed['feed'].get("lastBuildDate"),

    categories = parsed_feed['feed'].get("categories"),
    generator = parsed_feed['feed'].get("generator"),
    docs = parsed_feed['feed'].get("docs"),

    items = items
)
```

The original feed has a `<show_id></show_id>` tag, as well as an enclosure 
`<enclosure url="http://url.com" length="10" type="" />` and I need to include that in the generated version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. First, you could change the code directly. Edit 'publish' and put whatever you want wherever you want it.

But if you want to take the suggestion from the documentation, derive from RSS2 and implement your own publish_extensions, like this:

```
class YourRSS2Item(PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem):
    def publish_extensions(self, handler):
        handler.startElement("show_id")
        handler.endElement("show_id")
```

'handler' follows the SAX2 API (start_element, characters, end_element).

And as for making an enclosure, use the Enclosure class, as in

```
item = RSSItem( .... enclosure = Enclosure("http://url.com", 10, ""), ...)
```

Comment: How can I use this class (YourRSS2Item) to actually write my own elements? Can you give a complete example please?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation explains:](http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html)

> To add your
>   own attributes (needed for namespace
>   declarations), redefine
>   `element_attrs` or `rss_attrs` in your
>   subclass [of `RSS` and `RSSData`].

That's the whole point about subclassing, isn't it? :)

Comment: While I think I figured out 'element_attrs', I can't wrap my head around how to make 'publish_extensions' add new element to the item, as I haven't had much experience in python inheritance up to this point.